# Adobe Rush suddenly started running really slow on MacBook

Tags: adobe

Been using Adobe Rush 2.9.0 (build 14) on a 2020 MacBook Pro with these specs:

- 2.4 GHz 8-core Intel i9
- AMD Radeon Pro 5600M 8GB
- 64 GB DDR4 RAM
- Ventura 13.3.1

Rush was running fine before today and suddenly even doing simple operations like expanding the timeline causes it to use up to 4 cores to max capacity. At this point editing videos can take hours to complete while the cursor just spins.

Nothing else in the system is using any appreciable CPU.

There is tons of free RAM available.

I've tried restarting and clearing Rush's cache, but neither has worked.

What could have caused this to happen?

Comment: Were any updates done to the system? Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling Adobe Rush?

Comment: No updates to the system for the past two weeks. Haven't tried uninstalling and reinstalling yet.

Comment: Have you pursued the matter with Adobe -- after all, that's what you pay the constant fee for! I would then try the usual steps, like testing a new user account, and booting to Safe Boot mode. Also update to the latest Ventura, 13.5.

Comment: I'll try updating the OS to 13.5. Didn't realize there was a new minor update out. Fingers crossed that does it. So far Adobe hasn't produced a solution but I am working that angle as well.